# Is it safe to just rename a windows library on disk?

Tags: c, windows, dll, linker

I have a fork of a large open source repository that generates a library "tvm.dll".

When distributing my version of the library I want to rename it so that it can be differentiated from the upstream version "my_tvm.dll".

I considered modifying the CMake infrastructure of the project to update the name, but unfortunately it breaks a lot of the testcases that depended on the original library name "tvm.dll".

Is it safe to just build the project normally, then rename the library files on disk, and distribute them?

This would be the *.dll, *.lib, *.exp files?

For some reason I am worried that the library name is embedded within one of these files.

Comment: Yes, the library name is embedded in the *.lib files.

Comment: How about `find ./src -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/\<tvm\>/myNewTvm/g' -e 's/\<Tvm\>/MyNewTvm/g' -e 's/\<TVM\>/MY_NEW_TVM/g' {} \;`? (or whatever the windows equivalent is) Maybe you need some additional handwork.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 that is one solution, but it involves many scattered changes throughout the repo. The essence of this question is basically: Can I change nothing in the repo, and just rename the library file after the build?